# Program won't print out the number of letters correctly in a file

Tags: python, file-io, count, cpu-word

I am making a program that reads a file, and prints out how many of each individual letter it contains, if any. If the file contains "hello world" in it, I want it to be print 1h, 1e, 3l, 2o, 1w, 1r, 1l etc. This is not a work project or anything, I am doing it out of interest. I couldn't seem to find an example code that does this which is why I thought i'd ask here :) Would like to know how my code is supposed to look.

```
a1 = 0
b1 = 0
c1 = 0
d1 = 0
e1 = 0
f1 = 0
g1 = 0
h1 = 0
i1 = 0
j1 = 0
k1 = 0
l1 = 0
m1 = 0
n1 = 0
o1 = 0
p1 = 0
q1 = 0
r1 = 0
s1 = 0
t1 = 0
u1 = 0
v1 = 0
w1 = 0
x1 = 0
y1 = 0
z1 = 0
with open("song.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line == "a" or line == "A":
            a1 = a1 + 1
        if line == "b" or line == "B":
            b1 - b1 + 1
        if line == "c" or line == "C":
            c1 = c1 + 1
        if line == "d" or line == "D":
            d1 = d + 1
        if line == "e" or line == "e":
            e1 = e1 + 1
        if line == "f" or line == "F":
            f1 = f1 + 1
        if line == "g" or line == "G":
            g1 = g1 + 1
        if line == "h" or line == "H":
            h1 = h1 + 1
        if line == "i" or line == "I":
            i1 = i1 + 1
        if line == "j" or line == "J":
            j1 = j1 + 1
        if line == "k" or line == "K":
            k1 = k1 + 1
        if line == "l" or line == "L":
            l1 = l1 + 1
        if line == "m" or line == "M":
            m1 = m1 + 1
        if line == "n" or line == "N":
            n1 = n1 + 1
        if line == "o" or line == "O":
            o1 = o1 + 1
        if line == "P" or line == "p":
            p1 = p1 + 1
        if line == "q" or line == "Q":
            q1 = q1 + 1
        if line == "r" or line == "R":
            r1 = r1 + 1
        if line == "S" or line == "s":
            s1 = s1 + 1
        if line == "T" or line == "t":
            t1 = t1 + 1
        if line == "u" or line == "U":
            u1 = u1 + 1
        if line == "v" or line == "V":
            v1 = v1 + 1
        if line == "w" or line == "W":
            w1 = w1 + 1
        if line == "x" or line == "X":
            x1 = x1 + 1
        if line == "y" or line == "Y":
            y1 = y1 + 1
        if line == "z" or line == "Z":
            z1 = z1 + 1fwef
print(a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,i1,j1,k1,l1,m1,n1,o1,p1,q1,r1,s1,t1,u1,v1,w1,x1,y1,z1)
```

Answer (score 3):

This will:

- Read the entire file as lower case characters,
- Extract all characters found as a list and sort them alphanumerically,
- Print each character and it's occurrence count.

  ```
  from collections import Counter
  with open('song.txt') as f:
  count = Counter(f.read().lower())
  keys = list(count)
  keys.sort()
  for x in keys:
      print '{0}: {1} times'.format(x, count[x])
  ```

Comment: How do I get it to print each input on a line, like

    a1

    b2

    c5

Comment: Yep thanks that one worked except I want it to print it in alphabetical order, is that possible? Since the dictionary is in random order

Answer (score 0):

Try this... This will give seperate count of Capital and small letters.

```
import string
fp=open('song.txt','r')
file_list=fp.readlines()
freqs = {}
for line in file_list:
    for char in line:
        line=filter(lambda x:x in strings.letters, line.lower())
        if char in freqs:
            freqs[char] += 1
        else:
            freqs[char] = 1
for item in freqs:
    print item, freqs[item]
```

or else convert line to lower case after the for loop for only small letters.

Comment: Hey Apoorva, that seems to do the trick except I don;t know how to make it print out each letter on a unique line, so the first line would say "a1", the second line would say "b3" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach would probably work with a few modifications, but it's really awkward and hard to deal with (not to mention error-prone). What you probably want to do is use a Python data structure called a *dictionary*, that associates a key (a letter) with a value (the count). So you might do something like:

```
letters = {}
with open("song.txt") as f:
    for c in f.read():
        c = c.lower()
        if "a" <= c <= "z":
            if c not in letters:
                letters[c] = 0
            letters[c] += 1
for c, n in sorted(letters.items()):
    print("{0}{1}".format(c, n))
```

Note that `f.read()` reads the *whole* file into memory, and the `for c in f.read()` loop then loops through each character individually. If you're just counting characters, there's no need to break up the file into lines.

This is a common pattern in Python and you will find there is a standard library utility called a [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) that does most of this work for you (another answer here shows how to use it).

Comment: Hey, that one works perfectly. I'm still looking for more methods of doing this for my personal project, thanks!